# How to use \leadsto in LaTeX2e?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, arrows

I tried to draw an arrow with the command

```
\leadsto
```

But I get the following exception:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \leadsto not provided in base LaTeX2e.
```

So how can I draw such an arrow?

I tried to import `latexsym`

But then I get this error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.56 ...ecognition, gestures recognition. \leadsto
                                                   Multimodal input system & \\

?
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`\leadsto` is a math sign and for this only available in math mode.

You must enclose it in dollar signs `$...$` (or `\(...\)` for inline math or use it in display math like `\[...\]` or the `{equation}` environment

```
[…] gestures recognition. $\leadsto$ Multimodal input system & […]
```

Answer (score 21):

The package **amssymb** provides `\leadsto` and many other symbols.

A good resource for finding symbols and the packages providing them is the ["Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List"](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) that probably is already on your disk as part of the TeX distribution.

See also [How to look up a math symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol)

Comment: I tried this, but then I get the same error as when using latexsym

Comment: @Roflcoptr No, the error is different; look at Tobi's answer.

Answer (score 6):

If you find that you often use this in text mode, I would define a macro as below using the `xspace` package and always use `Leadsto`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xspace}

\newcommand*{\Leadsto}{\ensuremath{\leadsto}\xspace}%

\begin{document}
    Now you can use \Leadsto outside in text mode or $\Leadsto$ in math mode.
\end{document}
```

The `xspace` command decides whether to insert a space or not -- see [the package documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xspace).  If you don't want to load another package you can use it as `\Leadsto{}` for the case where you want to insert a trailing space. Alternatively, you could hard code in a space at the end of the definition as I can't think of a case where you'd not have have text following this character -- altough, I prefer the `xspace` solution.

Comment: Does `xspace` work well in math mode? That is, will this give the right spacing when used as `$x \Leadsto y$`?

Comment: Seems to for me. Did you try it and found that it did not?

Answer (score 2):

You can load the `amsmath` and the `amsfonts` package.

Comment: Good advice, `amsfonts` provides that symbol. However, the answer doesn't solve the problem of the OP because he didn't use it in math mode even when he loaded `latexsym` which provides such a symbol.